# How I can click on a "Continue" button to finish a survey in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, testing, automation

I try to automatize a survey page. Everything is fine until I reach the last button and I can't click.

What I tried:

```
 @FindBy(xpath = "//div[contains(@class,'question-12')]//a[@id='next']")
    WebElement continua10;
    @FindBy(xpath = "//div[contains(@class,'question-14')]//a[@id='next']")
    WebElement continua;
    @FindBy(css = "#prev")
    WebElement back;
 
    @FindBy(css = "#page-title")
    WebElement result_title;

    public void completeSurvey() {

        JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", ages);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", sex);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", start);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question1);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question2);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question3);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question4);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question5);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question6);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question7);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question8);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question9);
        //executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question10);
//        JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
//        js.executeScript("window.scrollBy(0,200)", "");
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question10a);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question10b);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question10c);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question10d);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question10e);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question10f);
        executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", question11);
        continua.click();
         disclaimer.click();
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath = "//div[contains(@class,'question-14')]//a[@id='next']")));
    continua.click();
```

The code goes through each step of this questionnaire. I need to click the last "Continue" button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that partiular next button you might need to define a separate xpath:

```
(xpath = "//div[contains(@class,'actions')]//a[@class='btn']")
```

Try this and let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As I see your locator is correct, however instead of presence you should wait for visibility of the continue button since it is present even before you selecting the disclaimer button. However until the disclaimer is selected the continue button is existing but disabled. So I guess it takes some short time to change the continue button to be enabled while you trying to click it while it is still disabled.
So, please change from

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath = "//div[contains(@class,'question-14')]//a[@id='next']")));
```

to

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath = "//div[contains(@class,'question-14')]//a[@id='next']")));
```